# Canvas flickering with mousemove event

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas where i click and drag the images but they keep "snapping" back to their starting point which is really annoying. I don't know why i can't work out the mistake i've made in my logic.

My `mousemove` event has:

```
function updt(evt) {
        var difx = evt.pageX - clickx;
        var dify = evt.pageY - clicky;
            offsets.cur_offsetx = init_offsetx - difx; 
            offsets.cur_offsety = init_offsety - dify;

        if (offsets.cur_offsetx < 0) {
                offsets.cur_offsetx = 0; 
                clickx = evt.pageX;
        }

        if(offsets.cur_offsety < 0){
                offsets.cur_offsety = 0; 
                clicky = evt.pageY; 
        }
    }
```

I made a jsfiddle to re-create the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jQkNv/1/

Click and drag your mouse to the right and it will keep snapping the images back to their original start point.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/jQkNv/5/)**

Changing it to the following worked for me.

```
    if (offsets.cur_offsetx <= 0) {
            offsets.cur_offsetx = 0; 
    }

    if(offsets.cur_offsety <= 0){
            offsets.cur_offsety = 0; 
    }
```

**edit** I stopped updating `x` and `y` and it seems to work.

Comment: Ah thanks. One thing i noticed though, when you hit 0 and keep dragging, the difference becomes negative, so you can't immediately scroll back to the right, does that make sense? Is there a way to solve that.

Comment: @Dave I updated my answer seems to work now. You have to slide the mouse position back to where you originally started to get it to go the other direction, which seems like the proper way it *should* work I guess.

Comment: Just remember to listen to the `mouseup` on the window object not the canvas or your mouse down will be stuck if button is released outside the canvas element.

Comment: @Loktar yeah i was hoping i could fix that some how it feels bit weird to me =/

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware haha yeah that kept happening to me when testing, was really annoying.